# Get image attachment to a post outside the loop?

Tags: attachments, images

What's the best way to display the URL to an image that's attached to a post and is outside the loop? This is the code I'm using to display the results:

```
<?php foreach($duplicates as $postID) { ?>
        <?php $postData = get_post( $postID );?>
            <?php if(esc_html(get_the_category($postID)[0]->slug) == 'group-a-first'):?>
                group a first (only) - <?php print $postData->post_title;?><br>
            <?php endif;?>
    <?php } ?>
```

I was able get results using `<?php print wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $postID ), 'thumbnail' )[0];?>` but it works only if a post has a featured image.

Comment: What is in `$duplicates` variable ? And do you want show a default image if post has not a featured image ?

Comment: `$duplicates` just shows the post ID. Just looking for a way to display the path of an attached image to a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [get_attached_media](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media) function and your current `$postID`

```
$images = get_attached_media( 'image', $postID );
```

this will return a WP_Post object. If you want to get the url, it's located in the `guid` key of the object. Use a foreach loop to retrieve them all.

```
foreach( $images as $image ){
    $src[] = $image->guid;
}
```

To use a different size image, try

```
foreach( $images as $image ){
  $src[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'thumbnail' )[0];
}
```